# Beginner Ruby Programmer- prints error on a practice problem

Tags: ruby

"Write a method reverse_range(min, max) that takes in two numbers min and max. The function should return an array containing all numbers from min to max in reverse order. The min and max should be excluded from the array"

`print reverse_range(10, 17) puts print reverse_range(1, 7)`

"its printing the wrong output, this is my ruby code"

```
def reverse_range(min, max)
  nums = []

  i = max - 1
  while i > min
    nums << i

    i -= 1
  end

  return
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `return` returns Nil. You probably want to `return nums`.

Comment: "prints error on a practice problem" – The error message tells you what is going wrong, as well as the exact file, line number, and column where the error occurred. It also includes a stack trace which tells you exactly how you got to the place where the error occurred.

Comment: Hint: `x.downto(y)`.

Comment: The quoted question asks for an array to be returned. It makes no mention of printing, so why are you doing so? A simple example is always helpful: `reverse_range(1, 7) #=> [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]`. Is that correct? Note that is not the array that is returned by the code in the answer that you have checkmarked.

Comment: One way among many: `min = 1; max = 7; Array.new(max-min-1) { |i| max-1-i } #=> [6,5,4,3,2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use direct function

```
max.downto(min)
```

OR create function

```
def reverse_range(min, max)
  max.downto(min).collect{|a|a}
end
```

OR

```
def reverse_range(min, max)
  min.upto(max).collect{|a|a}.reverse
end
```

OR

```
def reverse_range(min, max)
  (min..max).collect{|a|a}.reverse
end
```

OR if you want to use your same code, Just add nums after return in end of function body then code will be as

```
def reverse_range(min, max)
  nums = []

  i = max - 1
  while i > min
    nums << i

    i -= 1
  end

  nums # or return nums
end
```

Comment: `collect { |a| a }` → `to_a`

Comment: My understanding of the question is that `reverse_range(1, 7)` is to return `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2]`, not `[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.